# Can we join different versions of riak kv in a cluster?

Tags: riak

I am just trying to figure out if we can join different versions of riak kv in a cluster.

I currently run a 5 node cluster of riak-1.4.7. Can I join riak-2.0.X versions to the same cluster? If the answer is Yes, How is the data transfer will happen to the new node of different version?

I tried to search in official documents but I couldn't find what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, some versions are compatible, this is for instance how you can migrate to a new version of Riak without any downtime. You should look at the migration documentation( for instance http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.2.3/setup/upgrading/version/ )

In your case, you have a 1.4.7 cluster and you want to join a 2.0 to that cluster. I'm pretty sure that it'll work fine, as a lot of backward compatibility effort has been in done. Once that's done, you might want to think about upgrading all the nodes to the latest version though.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you please tell me what are OSS and EE?

Comment: OSS = open source Riak version (what you probably have), EE = Enterprise Edition (you probably don't have that, and you certainly don't want that since Riak has been fully open sourced recently)

Comment: thanks for replying. I will try this out soon and will let you the results.